# Multi object delete in Boto Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto, google-cloud-storage

I want to delete multiple GCS keys wih Boto. In it's [documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/gs.html#module-boto.gs.bucket) it suggests that there's a multi-object delete method (delete_keys), however I cannot get it to work.

According to this [article](http://www.jasonwhaley.com/blog/2012/01/04/s3-multi-object-delete-in-boto/) it is possible for Amazon S3:

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket("basementcoders.logging")
result = bucket.delete_keys([key.name for key in bucket if key.name[-1] == '6'])
result.deleted
```

However when i try the same thing for Google Storage it doesn't work:

```
        bucket = BotoConnection().get_bucket(bucketName)
        keys = [key for key in bucket]
        print len(keys)
        result = bucket.delete_keys(keys)
        print result.deleted
        print result.errors


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gcsClient.py", line 166, in <module>
    GcsClient.deleteMultipleObjects('debug_bucket')
  File "gcsClient.py", line 155, in deleteMultipleObjects
    result = bucket.delete_keys(keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 583, in delete_keys
    while delete_keys2(headers):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 582, in delete_keys2
    body)
boto.exception.GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: You should ask boto for the question. https://github.com/boto/boto/issues

Comment: Issue added to https://github.com/boto/boto/issues

Answer (score 1):

This uses S3's multi-object delete API, which Google Cloud Storage does not support.  Thus, it is not possible to do it this way for Google Cloud Storage - you will need to call delete_key () once per key.

Comment: any idea if it is still the same?